# Bluetooth concurrent connections

Tags: android, bluetooth

For a fest at my college, we are planning a quiz contest.
For the buzzer round, I was thinking of writing 2 app for android (we have a few handsets), one for the quiz master and the other for the contestants 
The contestants will be connected to the quiz master through bluetooth.

After reading the question, the quiz-master clicks a button in his/her app, the button in the contestant apps will be enabled for X seconds. As soon as a contestant clicks his/her button, the quiz master's app will flash the name of that contestant.

My questions:

Is it even possible to have multiple connections and accept concurrent (or multiplexed) messages from them in bluetooth (something similar to select() in unix/c)?

If possible, where should I look for any examples? What kind of problems will I face trying to develop this (I know reliability is an issue here) and how to avoid them?

I had tried this on laptops before and failed. But maybe I gave-up very early. Please help.

**EDIT:**
I gave-up the project (too many connection drops). I'm keeping the question open though.

Comment: I don't know much about bluetooth, but what it sounds like this would be handled better on a local wifi network. Either way, reliability will be a serious problem. Have you considered using a bluetooth pairing request as the "buzzer"? Since the device is identified, it should show which request came first. Again, don't quote me on reliability. Check out the BluetoothChat APIDemo, in case you have not: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: Have you considered going to a local hardware store and buying a few buzzers for a few dollars...?  Technology is not always the answer...

Comment: yeah, I've done that. Made a small circuit. I just kept this question open for gen brainstorming

Comment: also... the maximum connections to a master are 7 right? so you can pair just 7 devices with a master device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth supports piconets, in which a single (quiz) master can communicate with up [to 7 slaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Implementation).

So, at the Bluetooth level, this should be doable. I'm not the person to say if it's possible to implement using Android's Bluetooth API:s, though.

Comment: It says: "The master switches rapidly from one device to another in a round-robin fashion." that was my point of confusion. Will it be impartial? Does "rapid" mean rapid enough so that the lags are ignorable as compared to human reaction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read though this and the rest of the information available specifically for Android?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Aside: When I was in college we did trivia nights the old fashioned way (paper and pencil) but on the plus side you didn't have to worry about having expensive phone handsets in the hands of drunken college students! ;-)

Comment: I was the only dork pushing for the idea... Now I've made a simple circuit for that (oh hate wires!).