# How many Bluetooh 4.0 device we can connect to single android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to connect multiple bluetooth 4.0 device to single android phone and continuously getting data from bluetooth device to my android phone so many device i can connect at a time and get data. what is the limit of android to connect multiple device like 7,10,15,20.... ?

I want to use this chip in my bluetooth device and connect to single phone

https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/ble113-bluetooth-smart-module/

Comment: I don't thing it's possible.

Comment: but it is define here but not clearly that's why i put new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207033/connect-multiple-devices-to-one-device-via-bluetooth

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707690/bluetooth-concurrent-connections . You could also consider using Wifi-Direct as bluetooth replacement.